# I want to create HTML page which needs to show table rows and column by giving inputs by number of rows and columns

Tags: javascript, html-table, rows, dynamic-columns

I will be creating 2 labels and its 2 text boxes. By entering the values it must give me the respective output of row and columns.

IF I enter 2 for rows and 3 as columns .. the output will be 2 rows and 3 columns..

I'm confused how to use the javascript over here.. 
please help

Comment: Could you show us what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
<style type="text/css">
td{min-width:100px;min-height:20px;border:solid 1px #000;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('btnCreate').addEventListener('click', function(){
        var rows = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtRows').value),
            cols = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtCols').value);
        create(rows,cols);
    });
}

function create(rows, cols) {
    if (rows <= 0 || cols <= 0)
        return false;

    var html = '<table>';
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        html += '<tr>';
        for (j=0;j<cols;j++) {
            html += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        html += '</tr>';
    }
    html += '</table>';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = html;
}
</script>

rows: <input type="text" id="txtRows" /><br/>
cols: <input type="text" id="txtCols" /><br/>
<input type="button" value="create table" id="btnCreate" />
```

hope that helps.

Comment: thanks a lot... 

Its dynamically working online at JSfiddle.. i question is how do use it offline .. as i see no html page into it.. ?? 

thanks

Comment: please explain better what exactly do you need

Comment: you can run html pages offline, you'll only need to download jquery and use it locally...

Comment: What If I don't want to use the jQuery  and only make use of javascript, html and Css?? How i implement it?

Comment: i'll modify the answer to use pure javascript only. i always prefer jquery :-)

Comment: Its not loading in my browser now,can u please provide me html code which will have two textbox that i can use to enter rows and column.

Comment: changed, look now at my answer

Comment: its not working.. actually we have a misunderstanding here.. 
What i need.. when i run the code given by u and Psych Half.. I need the text box generating in that each rows and columns.. eg.. if i enter 3 rowns and 4 columns.. i must get all the rows and colums having text boxes inside each boxes... 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

modified Gal V's answer... that uses input instead of prompts.. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EKfut/)

```
<style type="text/css">
td{min-width:100px;min-height:20px;border:solid 1px #000;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function createTable() {
 document.getElementById('tb_container').innerHTML = "" ;
    var rows  = document.getElementById('tb_rows').value;
     var cols  = document.getElementById('tb_cols').value;

    tblHtml = '<table>'
    for (i=0; i<rows; i +=1 ) {
        tblHtml += '<tr>';
        for (j=0; j<cols; j +=1 ) {
         tblHtml += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
          tblHtml += '</tr>';
    }
    tblHtml += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('tb_container').innerHTML = tblHtml;
}
</script>
```

style the below code on your own way...

```
Rows:<input type="text" id="tb_rows" > <br>
Columns : <input type="text" id="tb_cols" >
<input type="button" value="Create Table" onclick="createTable()" > 

<div id="tb_container" ></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 

I will modify it.. more .. 

Can u help to add the text box in each row after the row and colums are created?? Any??

Comment: @user2881738 sorry but.. i am a bit busy right now.. so maybe later.. okay??

Comment: @user2881738 by the way.. where should the the textbox be added??

Comment: the textbox shold be added inside the each rows and column,whatever input we have given

Comment: @user2881738 umm... just like a spreadsheet? you can type in any row and column??

Comment: yea it should link textbox should be present inside each row box

Comment: Thanks a Lot Exactly i wanted this.

Comment: no problem.. and um... if this helped you. can you mark my answer as accepted by clicking the green check mark... i'd appreciate that